# It is proper to have an enum with a single value?

Tags: c#, enums

This is kind of a very simple question, but I'm really interested to know what is the good practice.

I have an system including a logging sub-system. Logs contain informations about users ID. The logging simplified is like this:

```
log.RegisterEvent(eventType, userID, eventDetails);
```

Some events are system events and they have not associated an userID. As the user IDs are positive integers, I consider that 0 means that the event doesn't reffer to a user:

```
log.RegisterEvent(eventType, 0, eventDetails);
```

But putting 0 there is just... not right. I thought of using enums, like:

```
enum UserID
{
    None = 0
}
```

But is it ok to have an enum with only one value?
It is better to use a static constant?
Or it is anothe better way?

Comment: I suspect this comes down to coding style. I'd personally set up a constant. Epecially since passing in an enum when you would otherwise use an int seems much more icky than an enum with one value.

Comment: Maybe your userID could be of nullable type `int?`, and then you wouldn't need the enum?

Comment: @Jeppe Stig Nielsen: Nice ideea with the nullable type int?. It integrates quite good with eventually adding logs to a database, where the UserID column would be nullable and int? as a type.

Comment: Also, most developers will understand that if the `int?` is `null` (`HasValue` is false) it means absence of a user ID, and if it's `42`, then that's the user ID. With an enum type with only one value, most developers will not expect that `(UserIDEnum)42` is used, since it's not a "defined" value of the enum. And the idea of a "magic" constant is not very good in my opinion. I can write this as an answer if you want?

Comment: @Jeppe Stig Nielsen: If you want, you can. Your comments have at least been valuable to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't like your enum because most developers will not expect that `(UserIDEnum)42` is used, since it's not a "defined" value of the enum type.

Also the idea of a "magic" constant is not very appealing to me.

This seems an obvious case for a nullable type, namely `int?` (also called `Nullable<int>`). Most developers will understand that if the `int?` is null (`HasValue` is false) it means absence of a user ID, and if it's 42, then that's the user ID.

So change the second parameter to type `int?`. and calls will look like this:

```
log.RegisterEvent(eventType, null, eventDetails);    // no user ID in this case
log.RegisterEvent(eventType, userID, eventDetails);  // variable userID is automatically "lifted" from int to Nullable<int>
```

Comment: I have accepted this answer because this is the way I ended up using in my code. Jon Skeet and Martin Liversage gave pretty good answers to. But using nullable int? was integrating with the types from SQL (used for logging).

Answer (score 8):

"User ID" doesn't sound like a natural kind of enum to me. It's not like there's a natural bounded set of users globally.

A constant value would make more sense:

```
const long UnknownUserId = 0;
```

There *are* cases where an enum with a single value would make sense, but it would almost always be for future expansoin.

Comment: Would like to know more about cases where enum with a single value makes sense.

Comment: @Gulshan: As I said, primarily for future expansion - if you have something where there's only one option available right now, but you want to design your API with the possibility of more available in the future.

Comment: Can they be used as a custom literal type? Like this description in typescript? https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/10676
Sorry, if I derailed from topic.

Comment: @Gulshan: Not in all the places you'd want to be able to use literals. For example, you could use them for `const` values other than for the enum type itself (which isn't terribly useful). While you could create a class with implicit conversions from each of your literals to the class, you couldn't then have a constant expression of that type via the conversion.

Answer (score 5):

It is better to use a constant - otherwise you would have to cast the enum value when used because the API really expects a number. Enums are for closed sets of values and user ID's do not belong to this category.

Answer (score 1):

Declare a the user variable as static const:

```
static const int NoneUserID = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the logging sub-system to define an overload that takes no user id.

In that overload you could just code a 0 as it is now the only place it will be used.

Answer (score 0):

Yes what use is an enum when there is no diversity in there.